# Is it necessary to check for linear independence when finding Jordan basis?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, jordan-normal-form

There a several ways to finding a jordan basis of a matrix $A$.  For this question I have in mind two methods.  Let $N=A-I\lambda$. Say we have already discovered several strings, say these two $v_1,Nv_1,...,N^3v_1$ and $v_2,Nv_2,...,N^3v_2$. Now we need a third string say length $4$. We can either (Method 1) start with $v_3$ and multiply by $A$ etc, or (Method 2) start with some $N^4w=v_3$ and solve for $w$ etc. My question is, in either case, will it be necessary to ensure linearly independence of the vectors that you find in the new string compared to the old strings? Moreover, are there any conditions that help you avoid this check?

A related question a posted earlier: [Under what conditions are $v_1,Tv_1,...,T^{m_1-1}v_1,...,v_n,Tv_n,...,T^{m_n-1}v_n$ linearly independent?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3663097/under-what-conditions-are-v-1-tv-1-tm-1-1v-1-v-n-tv-n-tm-n-1v)

Comment: It is enough to check the linear independence of the vectors that are eigenvectors (the ends of your cycles).

Comment: @ArturoMagidin  Is the proof of your claim achieved by multiplying $\sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{j=0}^{m_i-1}c_{i,j}T^{j}v_i$ by $T^{max(m_1,...,m_n)-k}$ for k=1,... until all constants $c_{i,j}$ are eliminated?  (I'm adopting same jordan basis as in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3663097/under-what-conditions-are-v-1-tv-1-tm-1-1v-1-v-n-tv-n-tm-n-1v)

Comment: It’s a standard result of Jodan canonical bases; you can do it by induction on the total number of vectors, and does in the end result in something like what you are indicating, but you usually apply $T-\lambda I$, not $T$.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin One more quick query.  Are jordan strings/chains of different lengths necessarily linearly independent?

Comment: Don’t know off the top of my head; certainly if they aren’t maximal then there is no guarantee.